# JS DOM - Highlight texts with button unobtrusively

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Basically, I have to create a button that when clicked, I need to retrieve all the paragraphs within the div and make their background highlighted.
Then I have to write the corresponding JS code (in an unobtrusive manner) to link the button to a function that highlights the paragraphs when clicked.

The button should act as a “toggle”, that is, if the paragraphs are already highlighted, then clicking the button unhighlight them. If the paragraphs aren’t highlighted, then clicking the button highlights them. The button’s text should change to reflect this so it should either say click to highlight or click to unhighlight. So far, I'm trying to create a function that iterates over these paragraphs but the highlight isn't working

** I know that the mark tag in html would highlight a text is there any way i can add that to my js code? **

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="task2.js"></script>
  <style>
  #poem {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    width: 30%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<!- Modify code to add a button ->
<body>
<div id="poem">
<h2> How Many, How Much  </h2>
<h4> by Shel Silverstein </h4>
<p> How many slams in an old screen door? </p>
<p> Depends how loud you shut it.</p>
<p> How many slices in a bread?</p>
<p> Depends how thin you cut it.</p>
<p> How much good inside a day? </p>
<p> Depends how good you live 'em. </p>
<p> How much love inside a friend? </p>
<p> Depends how much you give 'em. </p>
</div>
<button id="button"> Click to highlight </button>
</body>
</html>
```

js code:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = okClick;
}

function okClick() {
var allParas = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i=0; i < allParas.length; i++) {
    if(allParas[i].classList.contains('highlightClass')) {
        allParas[i].classList.remove('highlightClass');
    } else {
        allParas[i].classList.add('highlightClass');
    }
}
```

}

```
window.onload = pageLoad;
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new class highlightClass.

```
if ( allParas[i].classList.contains('highlightClass') ) { 
       allParas[i].classList.remove('highlightClass');
    }else{
       allParas[i].classList.add('highlightClass');
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code but the highlight isn't working, I updated my code on the question

Comment: Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2xoggdk/). Few modification done in your js and added a new class.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2xoggdk/)